# Python: inserting text only before certain instances of lines?

Tags: python

I have a file that reads like this:

```
Text
Text
<tag1> Line1 </tag1>
<tag2> Line2 </tag2>
<tag3> Line3 </tag3>
<tag2> Line2 </tag2>
<tag3> Line3 </tag3>
Text
Text
```

This repeats throughout the document. In every instance, I want to input a new set of tags (say, tag4) before tag2, but only if the tag 2 is **not** preceded by . I.e., I want it to read like:

```
Text
Text
<tag1> Line1 </tag1>
<tag2> Line2 </tag2>
<tag3> Line3 </tag3>
<tag4> </tag4>
<tag2> Line2 </tag2>
<tag3> Line3 </tag3>
Text
Text
```

I've tried this:

```
with open('document.txt', 'r+') as doc:
    for line in doc:
        with open('document.txt', 'r') as doc:
                lines = doc.readlines()
        
        for index, line in enumerate(lines):      
            if lines.strip().__contains__("</tag1>/n<tag2>"):
                pass
            elif lines.strip().__contains__("<tag2>"):             
                lines.insert(index, "<tag4> </tag4>")
            else:
                pass
            break
    
        with open('document.txt', 'w') as doc:
            contents = doc.writelines(lines)
```

This gives me an issue re not being able to strip lines (there's some blank space at the starts of some of my lines). If I use the singular "line.strip()", it does nothing to my file - I'm guessing because it's just reading one lines at a time so can't recognise instances of two tags across two lines.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're better off using an XML parser rather than trying to parse it yourself.

Comment: Additionally: You shouldn't call internal methods that have leading and trailing double underscores. `elif lines.strip().__contains__("<tag2>"):` should be written as `elif '<tag2>' in lines.strip():` (and you don't even need the `strip`).

Comment: @tlcgib Of course.  You do understand that there are several XML libraries for Python, right?  Pick one.  That's what I was suggesting.